# Python Script Terminated If Windows Version Less Than Target

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Introduction

Hi, I'm new to Python. I've been working around to resolve current issue. Its seems i cant found any result anywhere regarding this issue. I've been trying several ways to achieve this that we'll discuss at the problematic section.

## Problematic

So the first thing that comes to my mind is that to use cmd command in python script through os.

```
import os
os.system('for /f "tokens=6 delims=[]. " %%G in ("ver") do if %%G lss 16299 && exit')
```

its trigerring "ver" not defined. so im thinking to do the other way to achieve this "Pythonically"

## Pythonically

Alright, in python i can check windows build version by doing :

```
import sys
sys.getwindowsversion()
```

The code above will result stdout :

```
sys.getwindowsversion(major=10, minor=0, build=19041, platform=2, service_pack='')
```

The problem is, i cant execute anything from that stdout because of my knowledge limitation. Im planning to use "else if" later on to make the script quitting if the build version doesnt met or less than requirement. Im targetting the script upto windows build=16299.. so im thinking to turn stdout as string using the following :

```
from io import StringIO
        stdout = sys.stdout
        s = StringIO()
        sys.stdout = s
        sys.getwindowsversion()
        sys.stdout = stdout
        s.seek(0)
        s.read()
```

but it will be the same as before, i cant do anything with the stdout. Is there somehow i can achieve the specification?

Comment: have to assign the result of sys.getWindowsversion to a variable, then you can just access it later

Comment: What are you talking about printed text? `sys.getwindowsversion` does't print anything, it *returns an object*. You can access the attributes on that object, for your case, `obj.build` is probably what you need.

Comment: Its barely hard for me to explain the output, so i just call it as "printed text".. sorry.. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To isolate the build number:

```
winver = str(sys.getwindowsversion()).split(', ')
for i in winver:
    if 'build=' in i:
        build_lst = [winver[i] for i in [winver.index(i)]]
build_num = int(" ".join(str(i) for i in build_lst)[6:])
```

The 'winver' variable is the sys.getwindowsversion() in list form. Search for the string 'build=' for each element in winver. Create a new string from that element's index and isolate the integers. Final variable is stored as build_num.